# Correct Syntax to change default Screenshots and Screencapture save location?

Tags: macos, terminal, screen-capture, defaults

I would like to change the default screenshot location for OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 using Terminal. But this command is not working, where subfoldername = "name of my sub-folder" I want to store my screenshots in.

```
author$ defaults write com.apple.screencapture location -string “$HOME/Desktop/subfoldername"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 2 lines

```
defaults write com.apple.screencapture location ~/Pictures/
```

and the

```
killall SystemUIServer
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. How do I need to type my command now that the default folder location is modified? /usr/sbin/screencapture -cR "0,100,1400,800" "/Users/politicus/Downloads/NameOf_File.png" or /usr/sbin/screencapture -cR "0,100,1400,800" "NameOfFile.png"? I tried your two lines and my screenshot wasn't saved in the Picture folder.